# elements with bounded conjugate in a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose I have a number field $K$ of degree $n$, and $O_K$ its algebraic integers.
Could anyone explain me how to show that the following set $S$
$$
S = \{ x \in O_K : |x^{(i)}| < B,\  for \ each \ i\}
$$
is finite? (I think it's true) 
Here $x^{(i)}$ is the $i$-th conjugate and $B$ is some
positive real number.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you restrict the condition to integers in $K$, the claim is false. For eaxmple, $S\cap \mathbb Q$ is infinite.
For integers of $K$, note that the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $x$ are elementary symmetric polynomials in the $x^{(i)}$, hence they are bounded as well.

Comment: Oops my apologies. I meant algebraic integers. I fixed the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a common fact that if $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the absolute norm on ideals, then for any $\lambda>0$ the number if ldeals $I$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ with $\|I\|\leqslant \lambda$ is bounded (this follows since it's true for $\mathbb{Z}$, the multiplicativity of the norm, and the fact that there are only finitely many primes lying above any prime of $\mathbb{Z}$).

Now, suppose that $x\in S$. Then, by assumption $|N_{L/K}(x)|<B^n$ (if $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n$). And so, $\|(x)\|<B^n$ (since $\|(x)\|=|N_{L/K}(x)|$). In particular, since the set $T=\{I\unlhd \mathcal{O}_K:\|I\|<B^n\}$ is finite, and we have an injective map $S\to T:x\mapsto (x)$ we see that $S$ must be finite.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Could you possibly explain a little more about the map from S to T being injective? If I have some unit $\epsilon$ in $O_K$, then I thought maybe $x$ and $\epsilon x$ would get mapped to the same ideal? Thanks!

Comment: @TomMosher Of course you're right. I tried to think of a good reason that the fibers are finite (only finitely many units satisfy $ux\in S$). I have a solution--it comes down to decomposing the unit into a product of fundamental units [and a torsion element]) and showing that necessarily the powers of the fundamental units are bounded. It's a little annoying, but I think you can manage it. But, Hagen's solution is definitively better--so I'd just take that :)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the alternative solution though! I greatly appreciate it!!